# Magento version 2.2.5 doesn't support php 7.1.x and Magento 2.3.0-beta12 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0

Tags: magento2, php-7, magento2.3

**Magento version 2.2.5 doesn't support `php 7.1.x` and Magento 2.3.0-beta12 requires `php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0`**

> **Magento 2.1.x technology stack requirements**

[image]

> **Magento 2.3.0-beta12 requires `php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0`**

[image]

**Now, what should i do if i want to run both Magento projects ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, Magento 2.2.5 runs perfectly fine on PHP 7.1.x. You should simply try it.

The general and larger question that you have is:

*can I somehow run two different applications on two different php versions on the same server?*

Well, yes, this is possible.

For start, you could simply check this article

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696856/running-two-php-versions-on-the-same-server

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 for that, i will check it and update you back.